# fp-ts Using async function in middle of pipe

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, functional-programming, pipe, fp-ts

I have 3 functions, `f1`, `f2`, `f3`.

`f1` and `f3` are sync and return `Option<string>` but `f2` is an async function return `Promise<Option<string>>`.

How should I use these three functions in a single pipe?

Here is my code:

```
import {some, chain} from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable';

const f1 = (input: string) => {
    return some(input + " f1")
};
const f2 = async (input: string) => {
    return some(input + " f2")
};
const f3 = (input: string) => {
    return some(input + " f3");
};

const result = pipe(
    "X",
    f1,
    chain(f2),
    chain(f3),
);

console.log("result", result);
```

Comment: You have two nested effects (asynchronous and optional) so you need to compose two monads. Since monads don't compose mechanically you have to use monad transformers. I am sure FP-TS supplies `OptionT`.

Comment: Yes there is `OptionT` in FP-TS but I didn't understand how should I use it. Can you show me how can I use `OptionT` in above sample code? Thanks.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the [fp-ts library](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/). Very interesting.

Comment: please read its docs and help me solve my problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution using `TaskOption`

Here is my code:

```
import * as O from 'fp-ts/lib/Option';
import * as TO from 'fp-ts-contrib/lib/TaskOption';
import {pipe} from 'fp-ts/lib/pipeable';
import {flow} from 'fp-ts/lib/function';

const f1 = (input: string): O.Option<string> => {
    return O.some(input + " f1")
};
const f2 = (input: string): TO.TaskOption<string> => async () => {
    return O.some(input + " f2")
};
const f3 = (input: string): O.Option<string> => {
    return O.some(input + " f3");
};

pipe(
    "X",
    flow(f1, TO.fromOption),
    TO.chain(f2),
    TO.chain(flow(f3,TO.fromOption)),
)().then(console.log);
```

We convert all of `Option`s to `TaskOption`s using `TO.fromOption`.

Comment: Very cool.  This would look pretty similar if you used a TaskEither instead correct?

Comment: @wayneseymour That's correct. you can do similar with Either and TaskEither.